# How to remove() and undo remove() on page width conditional ? I don't need a hide or toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using select2 which takes in rails instance variables. Due to the design layout, I can't just scale down the original select2 input. I have to create another.

The problem: A rails partial including the logic for the select2 interferes with the logic I need for the mobile select2 feature. So, it needs to not exist, not simply to be hidden (display: none) , etc..

I was able to get the mobile to work by using remove() on the original partial, but how can I get it back. Maybe something with a page-width conditional, but I'm not sure how that would work.

this is the element / render I neeed to have removed then to have it 'un-removed': (haml markup)

```
.divider-row
.row-border.vOne
   #vCompare
      = render 'compare', :categories => @categories, :v_friends => @v_friends
```

my JS:

```
 if (screen.width < 760){
      $('#vCompare').remove();
    }
```

how would I get this information back, when the screen size was over 760? append?

---

Im trying to use detach and appendTo() as some have suggested below:

```
$('.compare-searchM').on('change', function () {
        $('#vCompare').detach();
      })



$(window).resize(function() {
      $('#vCompare').appendTo($('#vAppend'));

      sizing();
    });
```

haml / markup :

```
.row-border
#vAppend
#vCompare
  = render 'compare', :categories => @categories,
```

the detach is working, but I must not be understanding something with appendto()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `.remove()` you can use `.detach()` and store the jquery object in some other variable, like

```
$vCompare = $('#vCompare').detach();
```

in your media queries, Later you can use this depending upon your media queries. for more info look [.detach() | jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/detach/). hope this would help you.

Comment: Hey. I saw this in the docs, but it isn't working as I'm expecting. Care to help troubleshoot?   I've added updates above.

Comment: I have not seen any code storing your detached element? @stanleytd

Answer (score 1):

When you add the item to the page, try storing it as a variable first and then adding it from there, somewhat like this:

```
var vCompare = $("<div/>",{id:"vCompare"});
vCompare.appendTo("body");
```

The div object will be stored in the variable `vCompare`, so you can still remove it with `.remove();`:

```
$('#vCompare').remove();
```

And then add it back later with the `.appendTo();` line seen in the first code snippet.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use `append` here. But before you should get proper position from where you removing the element. You can do it via [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
So, when you want to restore removed element, use [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) on the found by index element.

If lists, or whatever, have a big difference between mobile and desktop, I'd prefer to create two lists, one of which is shown for mobile and another for desktop.